# How can i extract information from bs4.element.Tag and save it in array?

Tags: arrays, regex, python-3.x, string, beautifulsoup

Im trying to download all the list of songs from http://los40.com.ar/lista40/, i can download manually but i would like to automate the process. First i have extract the ulrs whith beatiful soup, but i can't navigate the result of that

For example, this is the first song in the list:

```
  var datos_cancion_1 = Array();
  datos_cancion_1['url_audioenci']         = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/010002713547.mp4';
  datos_cancion_1['url_muzu']         = '';
  datos_cancion_1['url_youtube']      = 'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0S3enulCT8E';
  datos_cancion_1['url_itunes']       = '';
  datos_cancion_1['posicion']         = '1';
  datos_cancion_1['url_caratula']     = 'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/010002713548.jpg';
  datos_cancion_1['titulo_cancion']   = '22';
  datos_cancion_1['nombre_artista']   = 'Greeicy;Tini';
  datos_cancion_1['idYes']            = 'Tini';
  datos_cancion_1['VidAu']            = 0;
```

And i would like to obtain an array or json like:['https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/010002713547.mp4','https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/010002713548.jpg,Greeicy;Tini]
[datos_cancion_1['url_audioenci'],datos_cancion_1['url_caratula'],]

This is my code, i hope you can help me:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import json
import re
import urllib

url = 'http://los40.com.ar/m/lista40/'
videos = []
response = requests.get(url)
bs = BeautifulSoup(response.text,"html.parser")
all_script=bs.find_all('script', language='javascript', type='text/javascript')
data=all_script[8:]
a= data[0].string

b=['https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/010002713547.mp4','https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/010002713548.jpg','Greeicy;Tini', datos_cancion_1['nombre_artista'] ]
print(a)
urllib.request.urlretrieve(b[0],b[2] +'.mp3')
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this:

```
song_list = [''.join(' '.join(i.text.split('\n')).split('=')).split(';') for i in data]
```

That will give you an array of arrays each one like this:

```
["'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/010002696230.mp4'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['url_muzu']          ''",
 "   datos_cancion_2['url_youtube']       "
 "'https://www.youtube.com/watch?v1Jw_mhoCiFY'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['url_itunes']        ''",
 "   datos_cancion_2['posicion']          '2'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['url_caratula']      "
 "'https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/010002696233.jpg'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['titulo_cancion']    'Cristina'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['nombre_artista']    'Sebastián Yatra'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['idYes']             'Sebastian-Yatra'",
 "   datos_cancion_2['VidAu']             0",
 ' ']
```

From here I think you are going to be able to order the final array as you wish.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Yes, i try it but the only think tahat im interested to have in my array is the value. For example ['https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/audios/dest/010002713547.mp4','https://recursosweb.prisaradio.com/fotos/dest/010002713548.jpg,Greeicy;Tini]]
I dont need values like datos_cancion_2['url_muzu']

Comment: you can delete all of that usin these two patterns with the re.sub() function:

pattern_1 = "\s*datos_cancion_[0-9]\['[a-zA-Z]*\_[a-zA-Z]*'\]\s*"
pattern_2 = "\s*datos_cancion_[0-9]\['[a-zA-Z]*'\]\s*"


re.sub(pattern ,  '' , element_of_song_list)